# Proving that $\frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$ is partially derivable at (0,0), but not continuous there

Tags: limits, continuity, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
How can I show, that this function is partially derivable at $(0,0)$, but not continuous there? Regarding partial derivation I used Symbolab, but the result doesn't look promising at all

Regarding continuity, can I substitute $a = x^2$ and $b = y^2$ and then

$f(x,y) = \frac{a\sqrt{b}}{a^2 + b} = \frac{a \cdot (1+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{a})}{a \cdot (a + \frac{b}{a})} = \frac {1+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{a}}{a+\frac{b}{a}} = 0 \text {    for lim a } \to \infty $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Finding if a function is partially derivable at $(0,0)$ means taking the limit of the function like so (the definition of the partial derivative):
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$$ and similarly, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h}$$

To show it is continuous or not at $(0,0)$, we need $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y) = f(0,0)$$

If the partial derivatives exist at the origin, but using the formula it isn't continuous there, you've proven what you need to prove

---

### Addendum

You can find the function isn't continuous at the origin by putting $y=kx^2, k\in \Bbb R$
so $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2} \\ \text{becomes}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\cdot kx^2}{x^4+(kx^2)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{kx^4}{x^4+k^2x^4} \ \text{with} \ x\ne 0$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{k}{1+k^2}$$
$$=\frac{k}{1+k^2}$$
which changes for all $k\in \Bbb R$, therefore the limit doesn't exist and the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$ as the limit doesn't equal $f(0,0)=0$

Answer (score 0):

Just note that $f(x,0)=0$ for each real $x$. Therefore, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$. By the same argument, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$ too.

For continuity, I would consider the curve $y=x^2$. If $(x,y)$ belongs to that curve and it is different from $(0,0)$, then $f(x,y)=\frac12$. But $f(0,0)=0$.